# Unable to access files on Windows 8.1 phone device

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, windows-phone-8.1, windows-embedded-8.1

I am using Json files for local storage for my app.  While using Visual Studio's emulator reading and writing to the files works correctly.  When I connect a device and try to run on that device I cannot access my Json files.

My json files are set to Content and Copy always.

Here is my try statement for reading the file.  I have tried two main ways to access the file `Current.InstalledLocation` and `Uri("ms-appx:///)`.  Both seem to work in the emulator but neither work on the device.

```
try
{ 
    var package = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
    StorageFolder folder = await package.GetFolderAsync("Data");
    StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("Users.json");

    //Uri dataUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Data/Users.json");
    //StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(dataUri);

    string jsonText = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
    JsonArray jsonArray = JsonArray.Parse(jsonText);

    foreach (JsonValue userValue in jsonArray)
    {
        //Build my model object out of json
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //Creating instance for the MessageDialog Class  
    //and passing the message in it's Constructor  
    MessageDialog msgbox = new MessageDialog(e.Message);
    //Calling the Show method of MessageDialog class  
    //which will show the MessageBox  
    await msgbox.ShowAsync();
}
```

The Output Window Displays:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
```

Edit:
The try catch loop is not catching the exceptions related to the file system access problem.

On startup when stepping through I am failing out at `StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("Users.json");`

Why I trigger the function through a button I fail at `string jsonText = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);`

The device I am looking to run my application on is running Windows Embedded 8.1 Handheld update 2 (its a ToughPad Panazonic FZ-E1).  Do I need to to targeting windows 8.1 instead of windows phone 8.1? It has been working fine with phone up until this point controlling the POS bar-code scanner.

Any help would be appreciated I am at a loss.  Could my issue be caused by settings on the device?

Comment: Rather than just the message, can you share the full `ToString()` output of the exception, including the exception type, message and traceback?

Comment: Upon inspection my try catch block is not even catching the exceptions.  The exception I was seeing is somehow from further down the function.  The mscorlib Exceptions do not seem to be causing any problems except kicking me out of my breakpoint step through.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a stream reader on it like below:

```
var myStream = await (await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Data")).OpenStreamForReadAsync("Users.json");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the properties of the json file. Right click the file-> Properties.

Check the copy to output directory and select copy always option in the menu.
 That should help.